# Spyder - Python CSV loading

Tags: python, spyder

I want to load a csv file in spyder:

```
import pandas as pd
california = pd.read_csv("...\\Spyder\\california\\housing.csv")
```

But I´m getting this error:

```
Reloaded modules: ipykernel, ipykernel._version, ipykernel.connect, ipykernel.kernelapp, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, ipykernel.iostream, jupyter_client.session, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, ipykernel.heartbeat, ipykernel.ipkernel, IPython.utils.tokenutil, ipykernel.comm, ipykernel.comm.manager, ipykernel.comm.comm, ipykernel.kernelbase, tornado.queues, tornado.locks, ipykernel.jsonutil, ipykernel.zmqshell, IPython.core.payloadpage, ipykernel.displayhook, ipykernel.datapub, ipykernel.serialize, ipykernel.pickleutil, ipykernel.codeutil, ipykernel.eventloops, ipykernel.parentpoller, pyparsing, cycler, kiwisolver, win32api, win32security, ntsecuritycon, IPython.core.completerlib, storemagic, autoreload, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model, PIL.PngImagePlugin, PIL.ImageChops, PIL.ImageFile, PIL.ImagePalette, PIL.GimpGradientFile, PIL.GimpPaletteFile, PIL.ImageColor, PIL.PaletteFile, PIL.ImageSequence, dateutil.rrule, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d, ipykernel.pylab, ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, ipykernel.pylab.config, spyder, spyder.pil_patch
```

I already updated both Python and Spyder, but the error keeps appearing.

Edit: Don´t know what I did but it´s fixed now, magic!
Thx

Comment: this doesn't look like an error, it just says it's reloaded some modules. did you try to run the code directly in the IPython console?

Answer (score 0):

Try without double backslash but instead one and add ***r*** in front your path this will only read the file. I presume you are using the whole path e.g. `"C:\Spyder\california\housing.csv"` (?)

```
import pandas as pd
california = pd.read_csv(r"...\Spyder\california\housing.csv")
```

Comment: Thx. But I got this `Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things,

- Try moving the file in the same folder, so you can read it like `pd.read_csv("housing.csv")`
- Type absolute path, (eq. in code snippet) and tell pandas yoru index_col, separator and decimal. Code eg. :

  `california =  pd.read_csv("C:/Spyder/california/housing.csv"", index_col=0, sep=',', decimal='.')`

Comment: Thx. But I got this `Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model`